# Scaling background image

Tags: html, css

I have some simple problem that I can't work around. 
I have the following html code

```
<body background='/freewifilogo.png'>
      <div align="center">
           <img src='/welcome.png' />
      </div>
</body>
```

I want the background image to have the height and width to 50 %, until the picture reach size of 300*300 px. Then I want it to stop scaling.

I have been asking Google and I don't find any answer to my problem.

Comment: Can you give us a fiddle?

Comment: maybe you can use media queries to stop the scaling. And background-size to have it 50%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to manage the size of the background image independent of the size of the page, you'll need to put it in it's own container.

For example:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="bkg"></div>
    <div class="welcome">
      <img src='/welcome.png' />
    </div>
</div>
```

Then you can use CSS like:

```
.bkg {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    max-width: 300px;
    max-height: 300px;
    padding-bottom: 100%;
    background: url(/freewifilogo.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

The `position: absolute;` takes it out of the flow of content so it doesn't affect the welcome image.

As an example, see [this Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/bobdye/k86ojg20/1/) I didn't have a welcome image, so for the example I replaced it with a heading.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you want exactly but look at this solution :

```
<body>
  <div align="center">
       <img src='http://www.getfilecloud.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/building-blocks.jpg' />
  </div>
</body>

body {
background: url('http://ahdimages.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/background-pictures-6.jpg');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: 100%;
}

img {
margin-top: 10%;
}

@media (max-width: 300px) {
  body {
background: url('http://ahdimages.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/background-pictures-6.jpg') no-repeat 50%;
}
```

}

http://jsfiddle.net/r0qz2xep/